# Is it appropriate to iterate over ints for random seed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, random, random-seed

I want to make three random samples of a pandas dataframe, while seeding random so that I can retrieve the data again at a later time. Is it appropriate to iterate over a range of integers to do this, or could there be any side-effects from doing this? Does it take away from any of the pseudo-randomness? Here's the code I'm using:

```
for x in range(1,4): # int for the random seed
    randsamp = df.sample(frac=0.1, random_state=x)
    randsamp.to_csv("./sample"+str(x)+".csv",sep=';')
```

Comment: Seed once in your program.  Don't keep reseeding after every draw, that actually destroys the behavior of PRNGs.

Answer (score 1):

No you should be fine. The "randomness" is not dependent on the seed value.